# Construct Lyapunov-Foster function given invariant distribution

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a discrete time Markov chain on a countable state space which is irreducible, aperiodic, and has a given invariant distribution $\pi$. Then the chain is necessarily positive recurrent and ergodic (so the invariant distribution is unique and is the limiting distribution regardless of the initial distribution). Further assume that the chain is actually *geometrically* ergodic, so that a Lyapunov-Foster function exists, but we do not know what it is.

Can we use our prior knowledge of what the invariant distribution is in order to construct a Lyapunov-Foster function for the chain? It seems that some nicely decreasing function of $\pi$ should suffice. If it helps you may assume the chain also satisfies detailed balance with respect to $\pi$.

This may seem like a weird question; ordinarily you would construct a Lyapunov function to *check* stability, not when you already know it. My actual problem is to study the stability of a chain that is a perturbation of this "nice" chain, and for that I need a Lyapunov-Foster function for the unperturbed chain.

Comment: No, I don't think you can obtain the Lyapunov function only from $\pi$. At least, don't think there is any "general" way to do this. The "canonical" Lyapunov function in the positive recurrent regime is $f(x)=E_x$(time to reach $x_0$), where $x_0$ is some fixed site, and this is not much related to $\pi$.

Comment: @SergueiPopov That at least helps with perspective, because for that $V$ you have $\pi(x)^{-1}=E[\tau_{xx}] \leq E[\tau_{x x_0}]+E[\tau_{x_0 x}]=V(x)+E[\tau_{x_0 x}]$ so that $V(x) \geq \pi(x)^{-1}-E[\tau_{x_0 x}]$. But I suspect this bound is frequently trivial in practice. Do you know any techniques in this general area (constructing Lyapunov functions for complex chains)? (It may be that I just asked the wrong question.)

Comment: Yes, that bound may not be so useful, since if $x$ is far away from $x_0$, then you're not likely to go to $x_0$ on the way from $x$ to $x$. By my experience in constructing Lyapunov functions for complex chains, I would suggest it's kind of an art: you try one function, if it doesn't work, you try to tweak it, etc.  You may want to look at our book, http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~popov/book_lyapunov.pdf  (published by C.U.P.)